# Run command and capture output in Ruby, without risking command injection

Tags: ruby

Does Ruby ship with a function/method to run a command and capture it's output without risking command injection.

For example:

```
out = `ls #{directory}`
```

would capture the output I want, but is insecure.

```
system("ls", directory)
```

is safer (as far as I know), but I can't capture it's output.

Is there some equivalent to Python's `out = call(['ls', directory])`?

Edit for @Eric Duminil

```
irb(main):001:0> RUBY_DESCRIPTION
=> "ruby 2.1.8p440 (2015-12-16 revision 53160) [x86_64-linux]"
irb(main):002:0> Shellwords
NameError: uninitialized constant Shellwords
        from (irb):2
        from /apollo/env/SDETools/ruby2.1.x/bin/irb:15:in `<main>'
irb(main):003:0> require "shellwords"
=> true
irb(main):004:0> Shellwords
=> Shellword
```

Comment: `Kernel#system` accepts the same options as `Kernel#spawn` you can specify an `IO` object for the output [See Docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-spawn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can escape the argument with [`Shellwords#shellescape`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html#method-c-shellescape):

> Escapes a string so that it can be safely used in a Bourne shell
>   command line. str can be a non-string object that responds to to_s.
>
> Note that a resulted string should be used unquoted and is not
>   intended for use in double quotes nor in single quotes.

```
require 'shellwords' # <- Only needed for Ruby 1.9
"ls %s" % Shellwords.escape("test.txt && whoami")
# => "ls test.txt\\ \\&\\&\\ whoami"
system("ls %s" % Shellwords.escape("test.txt && whoami"))
# ls: cannot access test.txt && whoami: No such file or directory
```

As mentioned by @engineersmnky in the comments, you could simply use [`system`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-system) with multiple arguments:

```
system("ls", "test.txt && whoami")
# ls: cannot access test.txt && whoami: No such file or directory
```

Comment: I'd like to mark your answer as correct, but (in the version of Ruby I'm using) system doesn't return a command's output, just its return code. EDIT: or for that matter, Shellwords (unless I need a `require statement).

Comment: Oh, I was missing a `require "Shellwords"`

Comment: @jones sorry, it's only needed for ruby 1.9. I didnt think about that.

Comment: Are you sure about that? I'm using Ruby 2.1

Comment: @Jones I just tried it on 2.1.5, it worked fine without `require`.

Comment: I edited my question to show what I see when I try to use `Shellwords`.